# uses-permission disappears when exporting app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I will start with, I'm an android NEWB. This is my first week with Android and although its been fun I think I'm going to stick with IOS development in the future.

But on to my issue: 
My app is very simple. It goes to a PHP script, grabs some data and displays it to the user.
Its running fine in the emulator and on a device when ran/installed directly from eclipse.  But if I export to an APK and install the app, it shows "Unable to resolve host MYURL: No address associated with hostname".

Its because the build is missing
    
in the manifest file. However I've put that string in the manifest file but every time I export the app to an APK the string disappears from the manifest file. 
I've watched it happen in real time, I have the manifest file open in Eclipse, click "Export signed android application", go through the wizard and right when it builds the APK the permission line just disappears.

Has anybody seen this issue before?

Comment: First-time for me. Try to add it manually maybe it works then? I also use a PHP script (to connect to Database).

Comment: I've tried doing it manually by just pasting it into the XML file and using Eclipse GUI to do it. Both have the same end result.

Comment: could you post the complete manifest? (when the permission is visible)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmpfpaxnrlbs2x9/permission%20issue.PNG

Comment: "Its because the build is missing in the manifest file" meaning what ?

Comment: copy/paste it next time in the question please :)

Comment: Try this, change `<uses permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to `<uses permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: The rest is the same as my own manifest files

Comment: "Its because the build is missing in the manifest file" Sorry, it should be "The permission is missing from the manifest file in the built APK."

Comment: Using "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>" yields the same results.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for another 5 hours but I found a solution. I don't know why this worked but it did. 

I added the permission to the manifest file, saved the files, exited eclipse and restarted eclipse. Then built my APK and it worked. 

Thanks guys for the input.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question: it was never clear precisely what the issue was, and a year and a half later the link to the manifest file no longer works, so the question can no longer be specifically answered.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It would work fine during debugging but when I tried to export the app it wouldn't have permissions and they mysteriously disappeared from the manifest file.

It turns out I was updating the permissions in the MyProject/bin/AndroidManifet.xml not MyProject/AndroidManifet.xml

Comment: Ahem, yes. This could easily happen. Solved my problem :P